# What are modern solar system applications of GR where approximation methods fail?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, solar-system, post-newtonian

It is often stated that general relativity (GR) provides the most accurate description of gravitational phenomenon. In most undergraduate and even graduate textbooks this idea is reinforced by discussing various **applications of GR** i.e. the precession of Mercury's perihelion, light deflection, gravitational time dilation etc.

However, these applications are presented in highly idealised situations where we mainly rely on the description of the gravitational field provided by the Schwarzschild and Kerr geometries. For example, when discussing the precession of Mercury's perihelion we:

- Derive a Lagrangian associated with a test particle in Schwarzschild geometry which follows a geodesic.
- Determine the equations of motion associated with said test particle which is given by the relativistic equivalent of the classical Binet equation.
- Use some perturbation technique to solve the associated non-linear ODE and from this obtain the correct value for the unexplained precession.

The system described is essentially the relativistic effective one body problem.

However, if we wanted to describe more complicated situations such as relativistic $n$-body equations of motion; no such expressions exists in full non-linear GR. We rely on approximation methods given first by [Einstein, Infeld & Hoffmann](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein%E2%80%93Infeld%E2%80%93Hoffmann_equations). Further, when wanting to describe phenomena such as the propagation of gravitational radiation we also rely on approximation methods e.g. the many recent detections of gravitational waves due to in-spiralling black hole and neutron star binary systems relied extremely heavily on such approximations.

Such methods are known as the [post-Newtonian approximation](http://www.cambridge.org/au/academic/subjects/physics/astrophysics/gravity-newtonian-post-newtonian-relativistic?format=HB&isbn=9781107032866) and are obtained by formally linearising the field equations of GR. They are a tool in which we can describe complicated systems where GR cannot due to its highly non-linear structure. Several formalisms exist cf. chapter by Thibault Damour in [300 years of gravitation](http://www.cambridge.org/au/academic/subjects/physics/cosmology-relativity-and-gravitation/three-hundred-years-gravitation?format=PB&isbn=9780521379762) for a review. Such methods have been described as *[unreasonably effective](https://arxiv.org/abs/1102.5192)* in discussing gravity and it is a well deserved accolade. When approximated to a suitably high order, the PN formalism can be used in describing very strong field gravitational systems.

**My question**

What are the **applications** or situations of modern-day gravitational solar system physics that require the use of full non-linear GR equations? Or, put another way, by linearising the field equations we lose some information; what are some modern applications of GR where such approximation methods fail to give an accurate description of the physics associated with them?

**A counter example**

If we wanted to describe relativistic contributions to **solar system** dynamics we would rely on numerical integration of the EIH equations. This is part of the process that NASA's JPL use in order to produce solar system ephemerides.

Comment: Gravitational lensing?

Comment: Einstein's field equations have the issue of not being linear. This makes them hardly, most commonly impossibly, solvable to gain an exact solution. Approximation methods such as the post Newtonian approximation are usually perturbative expansions of Einstein's field equations. So, eventually, GR is the theory offering these approxmations. In addition, what's the point of investigating complicated systems without understanding the physics behind it? That's where GR has the upper hand. It explains the fundamental physics behind everything AND offers numerical predictions of new phenomena.

Comment: I think you are confusing methods of solving the equations of theories of physics with theories of physics.

Comment: There's an entire field of physics where GR is regularly applied without making appeal to a post-Newtonian approximation, namely cosmology.

Comment: @tfb I don’t think so. Is it not clear from my question that I am discussing equations of motion and applications of GR vs. it’s post Newtonian approximation? I am not suggesting the PN formalism is an alternative theory of gravity?

Comment: It might be noted that there's also no known general solution for Newtonian gravity (e.g. the 3 body problem) yet we still hold it in high regard, and use numerical approximations to plan things like the trajectories of space probes.

Comment: @Rumplestillskin then I can't work out what you are trying to ask.  I think you may be confused by the absence of closed-form solutions, but that's spurious: essentially no real physical systems in any regime have closed-form solutions.  We consider ourselves lucky if we know that solutions exist at all.

Comment: @tfb I have updated the question accordingly. Hopefully it is more clear.

Comment: The question (v3) is still confusing: the title should be something like 'what are some applications where full GR is needed' which actually has answers (black holes, black hole collisions, cosmology etc).  It also still contains serious confusions such as the claim that no expressions exist for $n$-body systems in GR: they do, they're just hard to solve.

Comment: @tfb thanks for the feedback will update accordingly. I have never seen n body GR equations other than the EIH equations? Can you provide a reference?

Comment: I don't know of any $n$-body formulations which use full GR.  Clearly such things exist but they would not be very interesting except in cases where there are a large number of objects moving at relativistic speeds with respect to each other, or in the strong field regime.  They'd also be absurdly numerically intensive to solve, so without without observed systems like this no-one would bother (perhaps stars in close orbits around supermassive BHs?)

Comment: @tfb okay, so my claim regarding the $n$ body equations of motion remains valid then? The EIH equations are the $n$ body relativistic equations of motion. These are approximated. NASA’s JPL numerically integrates these bad boys for solar system ephemerides.

Comment: @tfb I have edited again. Hopefully now it is clear.

Comment: @Rumplestillskin Yes, I think so.  There's pretty much nowhere in the solar system where speeds are significantly relativistic or gravitational fields are strong: unsurprisingly the corrections from GR (and SR) are tiny.  If they were large then Newton would never have come up with his laws of motion or theory of gravity because they would have been so obviously wrong.

Answer (score 23):

The reason GR is praised much more so than those approximation methods you refer to is that the approximations are derived from the theoretical framework given by GR. [Post-Newtonian approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post-Newtonian_expansion) is simply a set of techniques used to find approximate solutions to the Einstein field equations. The reason people care more about GR as a whole is that GR gives a much more complete mathematical and theoretical description of the universe that has many important implications for the foundations of physics and the universe. The approximation techniques are just a toolbox to solve a specific set of problems in which a given parameter is sufficiently small; they are not nearly as universal.

Said another way, all the approximate techniques can be derived from GR, by GR is not derivable from the approximations, so GR is a strictly stronger description of the universe: it has more information and implications.